# Unit test before the build in. Net azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How do we include unit test in .Net azure build pipeline. Unit testing should happen before before the build process and when the unit test is Succeeded only then the build should happen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your app first to be able to run unit tests. Or you can just run dotnet test command which makes sure that first your nuget packages are restored, app is build and then unit test run.

Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive)

Here is an example pipeline:

```yaml
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '5.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions
  
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
  
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura'
    publishTestResults: true
    projects: 'MyTestLibrary' # update with your test project directory
```